# How does MDIL work for enterprise phone apps?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I understand the concept behind MDIL and the role of cloud compilation of CIL -> MDIL ..

My question is, what happens when we remove the "cloud compilation" story , how or what does the MDIL compilation step for enterprise deployed windows phone apps?

Is it the CrossGen.exe that runs as part of VS when F5ing in "Release" mode? Is the XAP that we deploy in our "enterprise" store in this case a MDIL XAP or is it the CIL XAP ?

Sorry if my question sounds confusing, as im quite confused with how MDIL works for the Enterprise store :)

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681686.aspx

The Microsoft recommended way is to use a PowerShell script `BuildMDILXap.ps1` that ships with WP8 SDK. Given a XAP file and an enterprise code signing key (that you get from Symantec) -- it unzips the contents, runs the MDIL compilation, code signs the DLLs, zips them back to XAP and signs the XAP file as well.

The script uses two tools - `MDILXAPCompile.exe` and `XapSignTool.exe` to do the work. The phone is perfectly capable of running the IL (JIT). In my experience (a simple LOB app with not-too-complex UI showing data from server) there is no visible performance difference with and without the MDIL compilation. YMMV.

While MDIL compilation makes the assemblies bigger, complex apps might benefit from it. I would watch the startup performance and perhaps any heavy computations (if applicable).